# Symfony: How do I pass `.json` as a part of URL in Symony?

Tags: php, symfony

I tried the following:

```
/**
    * @Route("/api/search.{format}", name="api_do_search")
    */
```

```
@Route("/api/search.{_format}", name="api_do_search", defaults={"_format"="json"}, methods={"POST"}, requirements={"_format"="|json"})
```

I want to use the URL `http://localhost:8000/api/search.json`

The router match command returns the following:

```
php bin/console router:match /api/doSearch.json


                                                                                         
 [OK] Route "api_do_search" matches                                                      
                                                                                         

+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                    |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | api_do_search                                            |
| Path         | /api/doSearch.{format}                                   |
| Path Regex   | {^/api/doSearch(?:\.(?P<format>[^/]++))?$}sDu            |
| Host         | ANY                                                      |
| Host Regex   |                                                          |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                      |
| Method       | ANY                                                      |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                          |
| Defaults     | _controller: App\Controller\TicketController::doSearch() |
|              | format: json                                             |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler  |
|              | utf8: true                                               |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am using Symfony 5.4

Comment: Which Symfony version you are using ?

Comment: @AhmadTawila I am using Symfony 5.4

Comment: Probably you did mistake and your path is `/api/doSearch.json` not `/api/search.json`

Answer (score 0):

There is some sort of a problem with the examples you provided. The first code examples use `/api/search.{format}` however the output of router:match shows that you actually defined `/api/doSearch.{format}`

This simply seemed to be the case of a typographical error, and it looks like `http://localhost:8000/api/doSearch.json` will work just fine for you.

If that doesn't work, update the post with your controller and route:match again.